# Amazon S3 files in bucket public by direct link by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to Amazon S3 and I've just created a new bucket and uploaded files. I see only myself there with full grants. I didn't add any policy.

However if I open an anonymous browser and hit the file in this bucket directly - I can download it.

How do I disable public access for direct links?

Comment: Oh hm... For some reason I have Grantee: Everyone with Open/Download permission for each file. Is there a way to make them all private at once? Very weird

Comment: There is no simple way in the console to do a mass-update of the permissions. You could write a script to do it, but it's probably simpler to fix them by hand or re-upload them correctly. Which method did you use to upload the files? It is strange that the objects were set to public by default.

Comment: That was https://github.com/chef/supermarket, it's a software for private installations however it's S3 uploads are public by default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into it more I figured it out. The software I was using is uploading files on S3 with public permissions by default.